# plotting a 2D graph

Tags: user-interface, matlab, graph, plot

I have 2 figures. 1 figure is called power and the other one called cost. So I want to plot cost vs power graph where cost is the y-axis and power is the x-axis. For example:

Assume the result of the cost edit text box is like this:

```
C1 = 300
C2 = 500
CT = 800
```

Assume the result of the power edit text box is like this:

```
P1 = 120
P2 = 150
PT = 270
```

So I want to plot a graph from this output. For example:

```
P1 = 120 when C1 = 300
P2 = 150 when C1 = 500
PT = 270 when C1 = 800
```

For your information, the answer will only generated after I push the generate button. So what I want is, once I push the button, there will be a result at both edit text and a plot on axes figure but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why do you want a callback from the axes?

Comment: @oli: im sorry. I have just realized that i dont need the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot your data, you can simply do:

```
C = [C1 C2 C3];
P = [P1 P2 P3];
plot(C, P);
```

See e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-27853.html for details on how to customise the plots.

Comment: That is simple and thx for it. But how about if i want it become a bar chart?

Comment: @raymond: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-8602.html#f16-53499 for a reference list of the zillions of different ways you can plot data with Matlab.